# TypeError: Error when checking model : data should be a Numpy array, or list/dict of Numpy arrays

Tags: keras

i have no idea what happened, i checked the type of my array and it returned `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`.
The Error is persist when i tried to predict my model. i already tried many things like manually trace each of the data and manually reconvert it but it didn't works.

**Shape of the Array :**

```
(435, 107, 16)
```

**Here is my Model Summary :**

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_28 (InputLayer)           [(None, None, 16)]   0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
masking_27 (Masking)            (None, None, 16)     0           input_28[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_48 (Bidirectional (None, None, 512)    559104      masking_27[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_49 (Bidirectional (None, None, 512)    1574912     bidirectional_48[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_5 (TimeDistrib (None, None, 27)     13851       bidirectional_49[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_25 (Activation)      (None, None, 27)     0           time_distributed_5[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
labels (InputLayer)             [(None, None)]       0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_length (InputLayer)       [(None, 1)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
label_length (InputLayer)       [(None, 1)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
CTCloss (Lambda)                (None, 1)            0           activation_25[0][0]              
                                                                 labels[0][0]                     
                                                                 input_length[0][0]               
                                                                 label_length[0][0]               
==================================================================================================
Total params: 2,147,867
Trainable params: 2,147,867
Non-trainable params: 0
```

**ERROR :**

```
TypeError: Error when checking model : data should be a Numpy array, or list/dict of Numpy arrays. Found: (array([[[-0.4663794 , -0.47222245, -0.47148052, ..., -0.47379518,
         -0.474394  , -0.4745456 ],
        [-0.4680164 , -0.46923223, -0.44672582, ..., -0.4745051 ,
         -0.47454518, -0.474545...
```

Comment: please add a reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

i managed to find the solution, i just write a wrong bracket. i was thinking the method took two parameter within single array so i changed the bracket and it's worked.

Before :

```
pred = network.predict((test_data, test_length), batch_size=batch_size, max_value=0)
```

After :

```
pred = network.predict([test_data, test_length], batch_size=batch_size, max_value=0)
```

I Recently reading people code and a few of them using '()' instead '[]' to cover up multiple array inputs, but i don't have idea why they using that.